# Issues with LED Recessed lighting with dimmer

Tags: led, dimmer-switch

I have installed recessed lighting in my home.

This is a 3 month old home and I got the light/ fan prewire from the builder

Below are the items I used:

- Topaz RH6/R/IC/AT 6" remodel housing for 75W max
- Envirolite 5/6 in. Recessed LED Ceiling Light with White Baffle Trim, 5000K, 93 CRI(EV607950WH50)
  http://www.homedepot.com/p/EnviroLite-5-6-in-Recessed-LED-Ceiling-Light-with-White-Baffle-Trim-5000K-93-CRI-EV607950WH50/206852536
- Envirolite 5/6 in. Recessed LED Ceiling Light with White Baffle Trim, 3000K, 90 CRI(EV607950WH30)
  http://www.homedepot.com/p/EnviroLite-5-6-in-Recessed-LED-Ceiling-Light-with-White-Baffle-Trim-3000K-90-CRI-EV607950WH30/206852530
- Lutron Caseta Wireless 600/150-Watt Multi-Location In-Wall Dimmer with Pico Remote Control Kit(P-PKG1W-WH)
  http://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Caseta-Wireless-600-150-Watt-Multi-Location-In-Wall-Dimmer-with-Pico-Remote-Control-Kit-White-P-PKG1W-WH-R/206754146

I did check for compatibility before I decided on the lights / dimmers. The light manufacturer's documentation lists the Caseta as a compatible dimmer

On my first floor I have 6 3000K lights with one dimmer and another 4 lights with one dimmer

On my second floor I have 4 5000K lights with one dimmer in 3 locations

All the lights go off of the prewire installed by the builder

I have noticed the below issues :

1) When I turn on the lights they come up nicely with full brightness, but after some time one(just one) of them flickers for a few seconds and then goes back to normal
This happens randomly, repeatedly. In one room, 2 of them flicker. I have noticed this behavior in all locations.

2)When I dim them to the lowest possible, one them flickers and eventually goes out completely. The others remain at the lowest level of dimming.

3)When they are turned off and I hit the up button on the dimmer(not the turn on button) all the lights flicker at the lowest dimming capacity and it takes a while for them to turn on

I intend to :

a) reach out to the manufacturers

b) do some testing with another brand of light

In the mean while, any thoughts /suggestions on how I can overcome these issues will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you calibrated the dimmers? Lutron Caseta dimmers allow you to adjust the low-end trim; follow the instructions here: http://www.casetawireless.com/Documents/0301710%20-%20Low%20End%20Trim.pdf

Comment: Calibrated as per the instructions. Still flickering.